# Unable to run mongo CL by python but succesful when running it on CL

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, redhat

I am trying to run this command using python and it is running well with mongodb version under 3.4.x, but doesn't work with 3.4.x.
This is the command:

```
su - mongod -c "/usr/bin/mongo admin -u admin -p password 
--authenticationDatabase admin --port 27017 --eval 'version()'
```

And this is the error that I got:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.14
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin
MongoDB server version: 3.4.14
2018-04-26T17:34:06.036+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1461:20@(auth):6:1@(auth):1:2:
```

However when I ran the exact same command on the command line, I got the expected result:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.14
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin
MongoDB server version: 3.4.14
3.4.14
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Why are you trying to launch a server and shell "inline" from your python program? This is wrong on so many levels, so it's better for you to explain what you "think" you want this for instead. Then we can tell you what you should be doing.

Comment: @NeilLunn this is for automation script. I need to get some information from the server (e.g. status)

Comment: You're starting the server, and more importantly you are not waiting for it to start. You need to be a lot more descriptive than "automation script" as to your actual purpose. Chances are you're attempting to "re-invent the wheel" so we need you to be explicit about what you are actually attempting to do this for, since we can likely then tell you what to do instead.